# Why do I need to link against opengl32 when I have glew32?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

Why do I need both the *libopengl32.dll* and the *libglew32* libraries when compiling an OpenGL program? What's the difference between the libraries and why do I need both?

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* (always) need both the `libopengl32.dll` and the `libglew32` libraries when compiling an **OpenGL** program. You need both when compiling a **GLEW** program (which implies also being an OpenGL program since GLEW builds upon OpenGL). For some people, this difference is academic since they would never consider writing an OpenGL program without the convenience of GLEW (et al.). However, GLEW is not required by OpenGL.

Your OpenGL library is the base upon which your GLEW library depends. You can use OpenGL without GLEW, but you cannot use GLEW without OpenGL. If your program uses GLEW, then you need to link your GLEW library because you are using it, and you need to link your OpenGL library because GLEW (and probably your code as well) uses that. If you are using pure OpenGL with no elements of GLEW, you need just to link your OpenGL library.

Comment: _"since they would never consider writing an OpenGL program without the convenience of GLEW"_ — GLEW is not the only extension wrapper. There're lots of others, including QtOpenGL, GLAD, GLee, ...

Comment: @Ruslan Well, yes. People who use the other extension wrappers are not part of the "some people" who would never consider writing an OpenGL program without the convenience of GLEW. They might be part of the larger group who would never consider writing an OpenGL program without the convenience of some extension wrapper, though. I'm just trying to keep my answer as focused as the question is. (Listing those others feels like going off on a tangent.)

Comment: Hmm... Maybe something subtle?